# how to remove drop down arrow from combo box?

Tags: winapi

I am working on a sample application to display combo box. i could display the combo box.
But i want to remove the combo box drop down  arrow.

please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without painting the control yourself. But there's no point to do that because a combo box that can't be dropped down is an edit box. Use one of those instead, perhaps supporting auto suggest.

Answer (score 0):

even with all of the common control library's support for owner/custom drawing, getting rid of the combo box is difficult to impossible. most likely impossible.

i would not have even tried if there weren't significant complexities involved to switching to a different type of control...

just my experience, and in a past life i did owner-drawn toolbars and such all day long.